# Template inheritance and varargs

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions

How  to implement `X` constructor and initialize `Base` class with variadic argument list?

```
#include<cstdarg>

class A
{
private:
    int m_a;
public:
    A(int a): m_a(a) {}
};

class B: public A
{
private:
    int m_b;
public:
    B(int a, int b):A(a), m_b(b){}
};

template <class Base>
class X: public Base
{
public:
    //X(...):Base(...)
};

int main()
{
    X<A> x(7)
    X<B> x(3,5);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not allowed to modify `A`, `B` classes.
Can not use c++11 or higher standard

Comment: How about using two different constructors for `X`?

Comment: Then they two need to be compatible with A and B at the same time. (If I understood your suggestion right)

Comment: No, you can have one constructor with a single parameter and one constructor with two parameters. Then use the appropriate one. As `X` is a template, only the members you use will be instantiated.

Comment: Yeah you are right and it is compiled with g++ but somehow not with Visual Studio 2012. Maybe I missed something else but that is not related with this question :) thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class Base>
class X: public Base
{
public:
    X(int a, int b) : Base(a, b) { }
    X(int a) : Base(a) { }
};
```

Yes, this actually works. `X`'s constructors are not instantiated until you try and use them, so all is fine. No nasty varargs to handle!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++11, I'd rather do

```
class A
{
private:
    int m_a;
public:
    A(int a): m_a(a) {}
};

class B: public A
{
private:
    int m_b;
public:
    B(int a, int b):A(a), m_b(b){}
};

template <class Base>
class X: public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base; //Magic trick
};

int main()
{
    X<A> x1(7);
    X<B> x2(3,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of a meta-trick using variadic templates.

using Base::Base; inherits all constructors from a base class.

Answer (score 0):

One C++11 way  would be to use variadic template

```
template <class Base>
class X: public Base
{
public:
    X(const X&) = default;
    X(X&&) = default;

    template <typename ...Ts>
    X(Ts&&...args) : Base(std::forward<Ts>(args)...) {}
};
```

One way to port that in C++03:

```
template <class Base>
class X: public Base
{
public:
    X() : Base(t) {}
    X(const X& x) : Base(x) {}

    template <typename T> X(const T& t) : Base(t) {}
    template <typename T1, typename T2> X(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) : Base(t1, t2) {}
    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
    X(const T1& t1, const T2& t2, const T3& t3) : Base(t1, t2, t3) {}
    // ... Up to N args
};
```